# menu are ID based so open in one page just scrolling down the page, how can I go the the page id from separate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have menu in the website most of them are ID based so open in one page just scrolling down the page, but I have made couples pages which has different page so, how can I go the the page id which which will scroll down to the id when I click the menu from the different page? Let me be specific, Here is the project which I am working for http://pasalnepal.com.np/yadavbhatta/ so the forum is separate page in the menu, so when I click on education, it should go to education part of the page.

Comment: your question is not in an acceptable format for this website

Answer (score 1):

This is due to some JavaScript code of your project. If I disable JavaScript in my browser and open http://pasalnepal.com.np/yadavbhatta/#education it will jump to the education anchor like its supposed to. But if JavaScript is enabled it jumps to the anchor and goes to the top of the page immediately.